# Multiple sockets or larger packets for high frequency data streams?

Tags: c, node.js, sockets

Im working on an application which uses NodeJS to communicate (as a client) with a socket exposed by a server (written in `C`). The server sends data from sensors and the client simply plots it.

Suppose I have 100 plots and 100 sensors. Should I open 100 sockets with 100 different ports or should I create some sort of *virtual* channel inside a socket by sending larger packets?

As it stands now I send 100 bytes at 50Hz where each byte is just dummy sensor data (`uint8`). Further down the road we will probably move to `uint32` to accommodate sensor data output, still transmitting at 50Hz. That would mean that each packet would be 400 bytes at 50Hz.

In short: multiple sockets or virtual data channels inside the packet?

Comment: What you call "virtual channels" could easily be implemented with a very simple protocol, where each packet include something identifying the packet as sensor data message, an identifier for the sensor and of course the sensor data itself. Sending these packets several times every second is easier and much less work (not to mention less resourceful) than using multiple sockets. Try something like that first, and measure the throughput. If it's only over a local network it should not be a big problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I figured that would be much easier. Is there a resource I could read up on regarding this topic?

Comment: Or, you could send one packet containing all sensor data as an "array"? Might be even easier still. 400 bytes, times 50, is only 20000 bytes per second, not a large amount of data.